# How to create a "hasBalance" modifier in solidity for any token address?

Tags: solidity, tokens, modifiers, msg.sender

I've been researching if it's possible to create a modifier that checks if msg.sender has any given amount of a token address. Use Case: limit certain functions to owners of a given token or NFT.

I've come up with this very brutal example starting from Storage.sol in Remix. It compiles, but I don't know if it would actually make sense. Any help is very welcome

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";


/**
 * the Storage.sol evergreen where only certain NFT holders (or NFTiD holder) 
 * can store value in the variable 
 * public retrieve the number
 */
contract Storage is Ownable {

    uint256 number;
    ERC721 nftAddress;
    uint256 NFTId;

// use this modifier if you want to allow all holders of a given NFT collection

    modifier hasNFTCollection {
        require(nftAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1);
        _;
    }

// use this modifier if you want to allow only the holder of a specific NFTid

    modifier hasNFTId {
        require(nftAddress.ownerOf(NFTId) == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

// only the owner can set the NFT collection address

    function setNFTCollection(ERC721 _nft) public onlyOwner {
        nftAddress = _nft;
    }

// only the owner can set the NFT Id

    function setNFTId(uint256 _tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        NFTId = _tokenId;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     * @param num value to store
     */
    function store(uint256 num) public hasNFTCollection {
        number = num;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, General node on your question: It would be good to ask a specific question or mention what problem you encounter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your proof of concept makes sense, remember that `uint256 balanceOf(address owner)` returns the total number of NFTs owned by `owner` for this collection.
Maybe you may want to check if the the caller owns a particular NFT in this collection, in this case use `address ownerOf(uint256 tokenId)`.

Furthermore pay attention to which token contracts are you interacting with!
For example if you try to implement this mechanism with an ERC20 and this ERC20 is listed on an DeX it could be possible to exploit your contract with a flash loan.

Comment: thanks @Andrea, do you reckon this modifier would work to check if `owner` has the `tokenId`?

```
contract Storage is Ownable {

    uint256 number;
    ERC721 nftAddress;
    uint256 NFTId;

    modifier hasNFTId {
        require(nftAddress.ownerOf(NFTId) == msg.sender);
        _;
    }```